# Converting Complex for-loops to Swift 3

Tags: for-loop, swift3

I have a for loop in Obj-C that looks similar to this:

```
for (int i = r1o.index - 1; i < r1o.index -1 + (32*r1h); i+=32) {
    // code goes here
}
```

I am busy converting my code to Swift 3 and I am not sure how to represent the above loop in Swift 3.  if the auto increment were i++ (instead of i += 32) I could do the following:

```
for i in r1o.index - 1 ..< r1o.index -1 + (32*r1h) {
    // code goes here
}
```

But it is how to handle the i += 32 that is throwing me.  Do I need to convert this to a while loop like the following or is there a Swift 3 for loop that can handle this.

```
var i = r1o.index - 1
while i < r1o.index -1 + (32*r1h) {
    // code goes here
    i += 32
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Swift 3 you can use [`stride(from:to:by:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/1641347-stride) for that.

```
for i in stride(from: r1o.index - 1, to: (r1o.index -1 + (32*r1h)), by: 32){
    print(i)
    //your code
}
```